# Make all endpoints to wait one exact endpoint

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, moya

I am using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/794) to handle HTTP operations and normally I have an `refreshToken()`. I am checking token if expired or not when a request is about happen but the problem is there can be a scenarios that more than one requests. If they are chained with nested types it is not a problem however, it is not likely all the time.

To be more clear lets say I have `request1()` and `request2()` and assume that they execute separate operations and can be triggered anytime(for instance one is called in a `viewDidLoad()`, other one is called in another `viewDidLoad()`). when this happens and if the token is expired, my refresh request fails. `(statusCode: 400)` So, my question is, how can I make provider to wait `refresh()` operation get done?I mean by provider is other endpoints. I want them to wait `refresh()` endpoint if it is on.

I will be very appreciated if you suggest a way that will make this easier.

Comment: Everytime before you call a request you want to check if refresh token is expired or not. If it is, then you receive refresh token through a service and then make the request. Just to be sure, this is exactly what you're looking for right? If it is then we can do it using closures and a global (bool) value for refresh token

Comment: I am already checking if the refresh token is expired or not before every single request. But as the my manager of network operations is async, sometimes two different request are made in a little time and they separately making a request to refresh the token. As a result of this, I get 400 from the second one. I am just looking for a solution to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set an variable called `isTokenRefreshing` true when i start the `refresh()` operation and checked it before making a request. If it was true I stored all the requests in an array and when the `refresh()` is finished I executed another function which basically makes all the stored requests in a `for loop`.

If anyone wants to see the code I can share. Just let me know.

> EDIT

This where I, `NetworkManager`, handle all my requests. It is in an `Singleton class`.

```
    private var awaitingRequests : [NetworkAPI] = []

    func makeRequest(_ request: NetworkAPI){
        if (Token.sharedInstance.isTokenRefreshing && request.requiresToken) {
            self.awaitingRequests.append(request)
            return
        }
        self.provider.request(){ result in ... }
    }

    func executeWaitedRequests(){
        for request in self.awaitingRequests {
            self.makeRequest(request)
        }
    }
```

`NetworkAPI` is main `enum` that I hold my `endpoint cases`. See the `Moya` documents if you do not what I am talking about.

And this is where I handle my `Token` operations.

```
class Token {

    static let sharedInstance = Token()

    private init(){}

    var isTokenRefreshing: Bool = false

    func refresh(_ completion: @escaping ()->()){

        self.isTokenRefreshing = true
        print("refreshing token")
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.asd.ads.makeRequest", attributes: DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent)
        queue.sync(flags: .barrier, execute: {
            NetworkManager.shared.makeRequest(.refresh(), completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                self.isTokenRefreshing = false
                if success{
                    completion()
                    NetworkManager.shared.executeWaitedRequests()
                }

                print("refrehing ended!")
            })
        })

    }
}
```